# How to create a gauge chart using JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to create a gauge chart using a combination of pie chart and half donut chart. The expected image is attached.
Can someone please help me to modify the attached code to get the expected result? Attaching the sample code, adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69473975/230513):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtils;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.RingPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.dial.DialPlot;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.PieDataset;

public class RingChartTest {

    private static final String INVISIBLE = "have_a_look_on_me_if_you_can_xD";
    private static java.awt.Color whiteColorAlphaChannel = new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255, 0);
    
    private static PieDataset createDataset() {
        DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
        dataset.setValue("Safari", 40);
        dataset.setValue("Safari1", 50);
        dataset.setValue("Safari2", 90);
        dataset.setValue(INVISIBLE, 180);
        return dataset;
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(PieDataset dataset) {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createRingChart("Overall Performance", dataset, false, false, false);
        
        RingPlot plot = (RingPlot) chart.getPlot();
        
        plot.setStartAngle(180);
        plot.setCircular(true);
        plot.setSimpleLabels(true);
        plot.setSectionDepth(0.2);
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        plot.setSeparatorsVisible(false);
        Color invisible = new Color(0xffffff, true);
        plot.setSectionPaint(INVISIBLE, whiteColorAlphaChannel); // 180° alpha invisible
        plot.setSectionOutlinePaint(INVISIBLE, whiteColorAlphaChannel); // 180° alpha invisible
        plot.setShadowPaint(null);
        plot.setLabelGenerator(null);
         plot.setSectionOutlinesVisible(false);
        return chart;
    }

    public JPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = createChart(createDataset());
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(jfreechart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(500, 400);
            }
        };
        chartPanel.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(chartPanel));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("BrowserShare");
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(48.0f));
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setAlignmentX(0.5f);
        label.setAlignmentY(0.75f);
        label.setOpaque(false);
        label.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        chartPanel.add(label);
        return chartPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PieDataset pieDataSet = createDataset();
        JFreeChart jFreeChart = createChart(pieDataSet);
        String filename1 = "C://Users//136965//Desktop//gauge_nut.jpg";

        try {
            ChartUtils.saveChartAsJPEG(new File(filename1), jFreeChart, 500, 400);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The graph created by the above code is
[image]

The graph that I am trying to create using JFreeChart library is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, look at `MeterPlot`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20MeterPlot), or`DialPlot`  seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20DialPlot), or the [gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info).

Comment: @trashgod thanks for the refrences. Was finally able to achieve using MeterPlot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also consider using [`org.jfree.chart.plot.dial`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/dial/package-summary.html). The example below use a `DialPlot` having an `ArcDialFrame` and a `StandardDialScale`. Three instances of `StandardDialRange` provide the colors.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.dial.ArcDialFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.dial.DialPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.dial.DialPointer;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.dial.StandardDialRange;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.dial.StandardDialScale;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultValueDataset;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70648615/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353270/230513
 */
public class DialTest {

    private static final Color LT_GRAY = new Color(0xe0e0e0);

    private void display() {
        DefaultValueDataset data = new DefaultValueDataset(70);
        DialPlot plot = new DialPlot(data);
        plot.setView(0, -0.25, 1, 1);
        ArcDialFrame arcDialFrame = new ArcDialFrame();
        arcDialFrame.setInnerRadius(0.42);
        arcDialFrame.setOuterRadius(0.95);
        arcDialFrame.setForegroundPaint(Color.darkGray);
        plot.setDialFrame(arcDialFrame);
        StandardDialScale scale = new StandardDialScale(0, 100, 180, -180, 10, 0);
        scale.setTickRadius(0.95);
        scale.setTickLabelOffset(0.15);
        scale.setMajorTickIncrement(10);
        plot.addScale(0, scale);
        DialPointer.Pin pin = new DialPointer.Pin();
        pin.setPaint(Color.black);
        pin.setRadius(0.8);
        plot.addLayer(pin);
        plot.addLayer(new StandardDialRange(0, 40, Color.red));
        plot.addLayer(new StandardDialRange(40, 60, Color.yellow));
        plot.addLayer(new StandardDialRange(60, 100, Color.green));

        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Overall Performance", plot);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(LT_GRAY);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Meter Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new ChartPanel(chart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 300);
            }
        });
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new DialTest()::display);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sharing the sample code with which I was finally able to achieve the desired chart. But the shape is somewhat distorted. Can someone help me figure out the error in this?

```
public class TradeMeterChart {

    public void displayMeterChart() {
        
        RectangleInsets insets = new RectangleInsets(50.0, 5.0, 1.0, 50.0);

        DefaultValueDataset data = new DefaultValueDataset(40);
        MeterPlot plot = new MeterPlot(data);
        //plot.setBackgroundAlpha(0.0f);
        plot.setTickSize(5);
        plot.setOutlineStroke(new BasicStroke(30));

        plot.setMeterAngle(180);
        plot.setDialShape(DialShape.CHORD);

        plot.setDialBackgroundPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.white, 0, 1000, Color.white));
        plot.setTickLabelsVisible(true);
        //plot.setOutlineVisible(true);
        plot.setOutlineStroke(new BasicStroke(30));
        
        plot.setNeedlePaint(Color.black);
        plot.setDrawBorder(false);
        plot.setInsets(insets);
        

        final Stroke outlineStroke = plot.getOutlineStroke();
        
        plot.addInterval(new MeterInterval("Normal", new Range(0, 40), Color.red, outlineStroke, null));
        plot.addInterval(new MeterInterval("Warning", new Range(40, 60), Color.yellow, outlineStroke, null));
        plot.addInterval(new MeterInterval("Critical", new Range(60, 100), Color.green, outlineStroke, null));

        plot.setValuePaint(Color.black);
        plot.setUnits("");
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Overall Performance", plot);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
        chart.setBorderPaint(Color.white);
        chart.removeLegend();
        String filename1 = "C://Users//136965//Desktop//gauge_nut.jpg";

        try {
            ChartUtils.saveChartAsJPEG(new File(filename1), chart, 300, 200);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TradeMeterChart h = new TradeMeterChart();
        h.displayMeterChart();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Clipping limits the useful stroke to < 12.