# Reduce the area of ​a MeterPlot chart with JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm creating a graph with `MeterPlot` in which I need 6 static values. It turns out that the graph cuts the top part and the part of the sides; how do I reduce that area? I already tried with this:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g2, Rectangle2D chartArea, Point anchor, ChartRenderingInfo info) {
    chartArea.setRect(chartArea.getX(), chartArea.getY(),
        chartArea.getWidth(), chartArea.getHeight() + 50);
    super.draw(g2, chartArea, anchor, info);
}
```

It doesn't work for me. As you can see, the image comes out cut off; I need it to come out central.

[image]

Comment: A `MeterPlot` works best with an outline stroke < 10.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, yes, but if I place < 10, the color line is very thin and I need it more or less that thickness. @trashgod

Comment: This [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70692566/230513) is an alternative.

Comment: Yes that is the approach I am following, but I am not able to reduce the area of the circle so that the sides do not intersect

Comment: You'll need either a custom `MeterPlot` or a custom `DialScale`.

Comment: meterplot works for what I need, what I need is to reduce the area of ​​the circle or if there is a way to enlarge its space so that the circle is not cut

Comment: You could alter the clip in `MeterPlot::draw` or the stroke in `StandardDialRange::draw`.

Comment: I am using the meterplot.draw, but no change occurs